# SignalR missing client call methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, signalr

I need to send strings in realtime to clients, but my code only work with sleep.
If I reduce the sleep parameter some calls are missed.
My hub class is empty, because I don't need client-to-server calls.
Here is my aspx file:
Client (aspx):

```
var myhub = $.connection.chatHub;
myhub.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
    $('#container').append(message);
};
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Server (c#):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Thread t = new Thread(novaThread);
    t.Start();
}

static void novaThread() {
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage("Server datetime: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You still need the hub if you want to invoke client methods on the server.  The hub is what perpetuates that connection.  What it sounds like is that you need a bit of renaming.

```
var myhub = $.connection.chatHub;
myhub.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
        $('#container').append(message);
};

$.connection.hub.start();
```

testHub means absolutely nothing if you're invoking ChatHub on the server.  As a result, I've updated your javascript to invoke chatHub, NOT testHub as you were doing.  By simply making sure that you're creating an instance of chatHub in the client, you should be able to get rid of your Thread.Sleep(1000) (assuming you don't actually need it for something) and you'll be able to broadcast to the client perfectly.

**EDIT:**

In light of your comments, it may be that you're actually spinning up too many threads.  Depending on how many threads you are running, you may need to raise the number of concurrent client-side connections per domain. The default is two. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

Comment: I would make it more clear that he's using the wrong hub name in javascript.

Comment: @RobG Fair enough :).  I added additional clarification

Comment: I copied the wrong example. I made the correction on the name of the hub. The original problem remains.

Comment: Can you provide further clarification around HOW it is not working?

Comment: I have an application to search for specific information in a database, but the execution of the search is slow (around 15 minutes). This search is composed of several queries. I need to send query results in real time to client instead of sending everything after 15 minutes. How can I do?

Comment: It sounds like you need an async task that queries the db.  When the task resolves, send the data to the client in real time and respin up the query as a new async task.  Would that work?

Comment: In example, if you remove Sleep or reduce value some method calls are missing. After execution client need have 20 timestamps.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the problem is not with your signal r hub but rather your data access.  Signal R will update the client just fine, but it seems like you're not returning everything.  Are you sure you're actually GETTING everything back in your query/queries?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Run this example and see that changing Sleep (1000) to Sleep (100) SignalR not process some requests. I changed DefaultConnectionLimit and maxconnection to the value 20, and continues losing requests. I can send the sample application by email if you want.